# Passing Multiple URLs (strings) Into One request.get statement Python

Tags: python

I am trying to have a request.get statement with two urls in it. What I am aiming to do is have requests (Python Module) make two requests based on list or two strings I provide. How can I pass multiple strings from a list into a request.get statement, and have requests go to each url (string) and have do something? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Typically if we talking python requests library it only runs one url get request at a time. If what you are trying to do is perform multiple requests with a list of known urls then it's quite easy.

```
import requests

my_links = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com']
my_responses = []
for link in my_links:
    payload = requests.get(link).json()
    print('got response from {}'.format(link))
    my_response.append(payload)
    print(payload)
```

my_responses now has all the content from the pages.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. The requests.get() method (or any other method, really) takes single URL and makes a single HTTP request because that is what most humans want it to do.

If you need to make two requests, you must call that method twice.

```
requests.get(url)
requests.get(another_url)
```

Of course, these calls are synchronous, the second will only begin once the first response is received.